# adding a foreign key into databases

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

guys i am making a grid library that uses hibernate and spring mvc to read data from db .. i have 2 table `employee` which has EPMID, EMPNAME, EMPAGE, SALARY, ADDRESS, department_id (refrences to department_id in department table ) and `department` which has department_id and name ... here is the Department.java

```
public class Department {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

@Column(name = "department_id")
private int depId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String depName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="department",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Employee> employees;}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "EMPID")
private int empId;

@Column(name = "EMPNAME")
private String empName;

@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
private String empAddress;

@Column(name = "SALARY")
private String salary;

@Column(name = "EMPAGE")
private int empAge;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
private Department department;}
```

and the function that adds teh employee in service

```
public void addEmployee(String[] list, Employee employee) {
    employee.getDepartment().setDepId(Integer.parseInt(list[3]));

    employee.setEmpName(list[2]);
    employee.setEmpAge(Integer.parseInt(list[4]));
    employee.setEmpAddress(list[6]);
    employee.setSalary(list[1]);
    this.employeeDao.addOrEditEmployee(employee);
```

everything goes fine without that line `employee.getDepartment().setDepId(Integer.parseInt(list[3]));` but i want to add foreign key to reference on the primary one ..
here is the exception

```html
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [sdnext] in context with path [/Spring3HibernateApp1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.dineshonjava.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:27)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.addEmployee(Unknown Source)
 at com.dineshonjava.controller.EmployeeController.doPostSave(EmployeeController.java:65)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **NOT** maintain foreign keys using something like this

```
employee.getDepartment().setDepId(Integer.parseInt(list[3]));
```

Instead do

```
Department dept = departmentDao.findById(Integer.parseInt(list[3]));
employee.setDepartment(dept);
```

Hibernate will now create the database relationship between department and employee by inserting the department_id in the employee table.

P.S. I am assuming some class and method names as I do not have all of your code.

> Regarding the NPE

I believe you received a null pointer exception because employee doesn't have a department at that point.

```
employee.getDepartment().setDepId(...
```